# Orbeon : setting email properties in the form itself

Tags: orbeon

I am working on workflow-send button.I set email properties in propeties-local.xml.

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.host.*.*"            value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.port.*.*"            value="587"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.username.*.*"        value="test123@gmail.com"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.credentials.*.*"     value="********"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.encryption.*.*"      value="tls"/>              

<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.email.*.*"                           value="true"/>
```

I am able to send mail by this way.

Can we add this properties in form diectly instead of propeties-local.xml?
Or any other way using that I am able to send mail without using this properties file ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible at this time and you have to set the properties. What is the issue with setting the properties?